# Issue about function overloads with different return type

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, types, parameters

I have a function that acts like this:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function MyFunction(ByVal param1 As String) _
As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)
    ...
End Function
```

I would like to add an overload that takes the SAME parameter *Type* but changing the return *Type* like this:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function MyFunction(ByVal param1 As String) _
As IEnumerable(Of String)
    ...
End Function
```

It could be done without changing the `param1` type?, I've thinked about adding *Type* parameters on both functions like `Function MyFunction(Of T)(ByVal param1 As String) As Ienumerable(Of T)` to expect an usage like this below:

```
Dim collection As IEnumerable(Of String) = MyFunction(Of String)("")
Dim collection As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo) = MyFunction(Of FileInfo)("")
```

But to do that I also need to change the `param1` value's *Type* and also I see the disadvantage of passing a different type parameter by human error like calling the function for example as `Return MyFunction(Of Integer)("")` and then add error-handling for unexpected type parameters inside the functions ...seems not a clean/safe way to do it.

So I explicitly want to use `param1` as **String**, the same function's name, and return a different enumerable on each function, I'm totally aware of a function that returns an **Object** or messing in this way with a type parameter, I don't consider this a clean solution:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function MyFunction(Of T)(ByVal param1 As String) _
As IEnumerable(Of T)

   Select Case GetType(T)

      Case GetType(String)
          Yield CTypeDynamic(Of T)(param1)

      Case GetType(FileInfo)
          Yield CTypeDynamic(Of T)(New FileInfo(param1))

      Case Else
          Throw New ArgumentException("Unexpected Type parameter", "T")

   End Case

End Function
```

Which could be a clean way to solve this issue? ...this is really doable with the requirements that I exposed?

Comment: How would you like the called to say which one should get called (assuming your code compiles)? Methods cannot be overloaded just by return type.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The 'how' is for what I'm asking for... I'm conscious of what you mean but on the other hand maybe there is something (something in this huge language that is unknown for me) that could serve to solve this specific issue, I just would like to hear the possible alternatives that aren't: '*change the function name*' nor '*change the type parameter*' and that. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, the *de jure/facto* is to simply rename each function to reflect the return type. In fact, this is the *only* approach I recommend.

```
Public Shared Iterator Function GetStrings(ByVal param1 As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
End Function

Public Shared Iterator Function GetFiles(ByVal param1 As String) As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)
End Function
```

---

**Option 1**

But if you can live with a couple of ambiguous warnings then one option is to create a custom return type which implements [IEnumerable(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Public Class MyFunctionIterator
    Implements IEnumerable, IEnumerable(Of String), IEnumerable(Of FileInfo)

    Friend Sub New(param1 As String)
        Me.param1 = param1
    End Sub

    Private param1 As String

    Public Iterator Function GetStrings() As IEnumerator(Of String) Implements IEnumerable(Of String).GetEnumerator
        For Each item As String In {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
            Yield item
        Next
    End Function

    Public Iterator Function GetFiles() As IEnumerator(Of FileInfo) Implements IEnumerable(Of FileInfo).GetEnumerator
        For Each name As String In Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))
            Yield New FileInfo(name)
        Next
    End Function

    Private Iterator Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Function

End Class
```

```
Public Shared Function MyFunction(ByVal param1 As String) As MyFunctionIterator
    Return New MyFunctionIterator(param1)
End Function
```

<sub>**Usage**</sub>

```
Dim collection1 As IEnumerable(Of String) = MyFunction("...")
Dim collection2 As IEnumerable(Of FileInfo) = MyFunction("...")

For Each s In collection1
    Debug.Write(s & ", ")
Next

Debug.WriteLine("")

For Each fi In collection2
    Debug.Write(fi.Name & ", ")
Next
```

> a, b, c, d, 
>   desktop.ini, file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt,

---

**Option 2**

Another option, if you're *not* working with interfaces, is to create a custom return type and define [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh17yw4c.aspx).

```
Public Class MyFunctionResult

    Friend Sub New(param1 As String)
        Me.param1 = param1
    End Sub

    Private param1 As String

    Public Function GetString() As String
        Return ("Hello " & Me.param1 & "!")
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As MyFunctionResult) As String
        Return value.GetString()
    End Operator

    Public Function GetFile() As FileInfo
        Return New FileInfo(Me.param1)
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As MyFunctionResult) As FileInfo
        Return value.GetFile()
    End Operator

End Class
```

```
Public Shared Function MyFunction(ByVal param1 As String) As MyFunctionResult
    Return New MyFunctionResult(param1)
End Function
```

<sub>**Usage**</sub>

```
Dim s As String = MyFunction("Bjørn")
Dim fi As FileInfo = MyFunction("C:\Users\bjorn\Documents\file1.txt")

Debug.WriteLine(s)
Debug.WriteLine(fi.Name)
```

> Hello Bjørn!
>   file1.txt